# Error viewing articles/pages after assigning

Tags: nodes, 8, workflows

As an experiment I've merged core from 8.3.x branch to try out workflow. After successfully assigning 'editorial workflow' to articles and pages, I cannot access the pages or articles anymore neither to read them as a guest or to edit them as an admin.

Visiting /admin/reports/status, I see this error:

> Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
>   The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
>
> - Comment
>
>   The Publishing status field needs to be updated.

My expectation is that the existing entities needs their workflow states to be set, but I expected the workflow module to automatically assign 'published' state to published articles. How can I fix that?

I was wrong about that this was only happening with existing articles. Another article after been created as well started behaving the same.
This was the error from log:

> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'content_moderation_state_field_data.workflow' in 'where clause': SELECT base_table.revision_id AS revision_id, base_table.id AS id
>       FROM 
>       {content_moderation_state} base_table
>       INNER JOIN {content_moderation_state_field_data} content_moderation_state_field_data ON content_moderation_state_field_data.id = base_table.id
>       WHERE (content_moderation_state_field_data.content_entity_type_id IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0)) AND (content_moderation_state_field_data.content_entity_id IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1)) AND (content_moderation_state_field_data.workflow IN (:db_condition_placeholder_2)) AND (content_moderation_state_field_data.default_langcode IN (:db_condition_placeholder_3)); Array
>       (
>           [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => node
>           [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 8
>           [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => editorial
>           [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => 1
>       )
>        in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadByProperties() (line 503 of \core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase.php)."
>   Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE…

Answer (score 0):

Missing column of the contrib module indicates the corruption of the database. In your case `workflow` field is missing in `content_moderation_state_field_data`.

If this error start happening after upgrade, try running *Database Update* (either by going to `/update.php` or running `drush updb` command).

There is a [Unofficial content_moderation 8.2.x to 8.3.0 upgrade path](https://www.drupal.org/node/2846618) which can also help. It has relevant patches for `content_moderation` module with update hooks, which will migrate the tables accordingly.

Otherwise you'll have to reinstall the module, so its tables are re-created from scratch.